# connectionstring declare in iis without declaring in web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, web-config

I want to declare my connection string in IIS and get it from there. I don't want to declare it in web.config page. Rather I need to know if is it possible to get the string from iis in web.config or read it from code file. I am using asp.net 4.0.,coding in c# and server is IIS7.5

Comment: What's wrong with the `web.config`? What did it do to you? Is there a particular reason it doesn't suit your use case?

Comment: Just curious where do you think the connection string in IIS would be stored, i guess `web.config` (glad to know if there is something else)

Comment: A lot of website-specific settings (e.g. handlers) are stored in the `web.config`... Please tell what is wrong with storing it in web.config and how you would like to store it then.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.But I just want to know is it possible to set connection string in iis and get it from there without declaring the string in web.config

Answer (score 3):

According to [this article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731800%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) you can use the IIS UI, or the command line to modify your connection string, but this will just write into the `<connectionString>` element in the web.config file any way (unless you've set it up to save elsewhere).

Also, you can store it in another .config file if you wish, and pull it into your web.config like so

```
<appSettings file="../VirtualDirectory/config/Env.config">
</appSettings>
```

You could then call it like so in your code:

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DefaultConn"]
```

This can be quite useful if you want the location of your connection string to not be under your site (i.e. in a virtual directory).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't want to read it from another web.config file. I want to read it from iis without declaring it in any web.config .Is it possible?

Comment: @polin It can be done, since it's basically just a line of text, but I would recommend against it. One option I found was to store it in the registry. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792911/storing-connection-strings-in-registry http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3881/Working-with-Windows-Registry-using-VB-NET

Answer (score 0):

You should put your connection string in the web.config. Putting your connection string elsewhere might not be portable, like moving from machine to machine. You also have the machine.config

In all, put in the web.config and you can encrypt it if you care about the secrecy

You can also have a separate config file e.g. db.config referenced from your web.config using the `configSource` attribute.

```
<connectionStringss configSource="Configuration\db.config" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't want to read it from another web.config file. I want to read it from iis without declaring it in any web.config .Is it possible?